# React Native add data to Async Storage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm developing application about travelling, so I have a map with places to travel and I want to implement adding to favourites functionality. When the user clicks on the marker on the map I show him modal window with all the information about the place and there I have icon-button "add-to-favorites". When user clicked on this "add-to-favourites" icon-button I want to save the place to the AsyncStorage, rerender icon to "remove-from-favourites" then if the place in favouries and user clicks on "remove-from-favorites" then remove place from AsyncStorage and rerender icon the add-to-favorites. I don't really understand how to do it in a right way in functional component. Give me an example please.

What I tried:

My ModalWindow code:

```js
const [favourite, setFavourite] = useState(false); 
const onHeartPress = async () => {
        setFavourite(prev => !prev);
        await storage.save({
            key: 'markers',
            data: {
                marker: marker
            },
            expires: null
        })

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onHeartPress()}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center"}}>
                    {favourite ? <Ionicons size={height/20} name={'heart-dislike'} /> : <Ionicons size={height/20} name={'heart'} />}
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

It's not difficult to understand how to add to the storage and then load from the storage but how to render the icon correctly like heart/dislike heart because now with this code when I press on button icon in one place in the other places it also changes, because favourite becomes true so I want to understand how in the correct way change icon only for place where user clicked on icon.

Comment: Please show what you tried!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code to achieve this functionality:

```
const STORAGE_KEY = '@icon_name'

// Store data
const saveData = async () => {
try {
   await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, age)
   alert('Data successfully saved')
  } catch (e) {
   alert('Failed to save the data to the storage')
 }
}

// fetch data
const readData = async () => {
  try {
    const userAge = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY)

    if (userAge !== null) {
      setAge(userAge)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert('Failed to fetch the data from storage')
  }
}

//remove data
try {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(STORAGE_KEY);
    console.log('Data removed')
}
catch(exception) {
    console.log(exception)
}
```